# Why is $0^{-\infty}$ not an indeterminate form?

Tags: limits

Wikipedia says the expression $0^{-\infty}$ is equivalent to $1/0$. How can I prove this?

Comment: What does being "equivalent" mean in this statement?  Can you link to precisely *where* wikipedia says this.

Comment: @fleablood https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#Expressions_that_are_not_indeterminate_forms

Comment: It's not an indeterminate form becuase it can be directly concluded that the value of the limit is either $\infty$, $-\infty$ or undefined depending on the domain of the limit. In any case, the limit can be determined and hence $0^{-\infty}$ is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: Wikipedia demonstrates this in the very next line where they say 'to see this..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$, then$$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)^{f(x)}=\frac1{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)^{-f(x)}}$$and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)^{-f(x)}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac {1}{0} $ is not a real number but if you want to convince yourself that $0^{-\infty}=\frac {1}{0}$ you may argue that $$0^{-\infty}=\frac {1}{0^{\infty}}$$

You may argue that since $$0\le 0^{\infty} \le (1/2)^{\infty}=0$$

Thus $0^{\infty}=0$